# NAT configuration with dhcpcd.conf?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, raspberry-pi, nat

Hello fellow superusers,

I would like to use a Pi (Debian based) as router right behind the modem/router. All LAN traffic will be filtered through the Pi, with a firewall after, not covered here.

So, I have two LANs, an "inner" LAN containing my local machines, and a small LAN between the modem/router and the Pi router.

I have successfully defined the route from the "inner LAN" to the "small LAN" beyond the Pi. My problem is I have a standard Internet modem/router, which I cannot configure routes on using "via". So, to counter this limitation, I thought of enabling NAT passthrough on the Pi's interface connected to the "small LAN" (where the modem is).

I repeat, on one branch I have successfully configured `ip route` setup, while on the other branch I need NAT passthrough defined at Pi's level.

For NAT I tried using ufw:

/etc/ufw/before.rules:

'# NAT table rules

*nat

:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

'# Forward traffic through eth0 - Change to match you out-interface

-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.x.x/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

'# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't

'# be processed

COMMIT

after reboot, disable, enable of ufw I get the following error:

**error around "*nat".**

actually I don't know if

> -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.x.x/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

is correct. The interface link is expected to route the traffic through, but I don't konw if it is the source link or the destination link. Anyway, the error might also be elsewhere (around *nat).

Remember, in one direction, WAN to LAN, I need to forward traffic. In the opposite direction I already have routes in place (I can't have the symmetrical because the modem is limited).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like it has nothing to do with dhcpcd(.conf) but you are merely looking for a proper way to make iptables rules persistent...

Comment: Literally `.x.x`?

Comment: `/24` doesn't really make sense for (the non-literal) `.x.x` anyway. It should either be `.0.0/16` if you mean "any" by `x` or `.x.x/32` (and `/32` can be omitted) if you mean specific numbers by `x`. (Well, or `.x.0/24`.)

Comment: Btw, has `'# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't '# be processed COMMIT` really become one line?

Comment: hi, .x.x means I don't disclose my ips, don't worry. I corrected the line breaks, it was a markdown issue, the original file is correct in syntax regarding your remarks.

Comment: I know right. You can keep on not disclosing it while it doesn't even matter. It's a private IP. And the point still stands (regarding network address / prefix length). But as long as it isn't literally `.x.x`, it shouldn't cause error (though it doesn't mean it will work correctly), unless ufw does extra checking.

Answer (score 0):

For addresses, use the `static` keyword in dhcpcd.conf – you can specify some static parameters while still using DHCP, or you can even specify a static IP address without having dhcpcd request a DHCP lease at all.

For iptables, first check whether the distribution already has its own services for rule persistence. For example, Arch has `iptables.service` which always loads '/etc/iptables/iptables.rules', while Debian has `netfilter-persistent.service` which loads (and saves) '/etc/iptables/rules.v4'.

If such a service is not available, write one. It's perfectly fine to add these iptables rules on startup even before IP configuration happens.

And for commands which *really* need to be run after dhcpcd is done and no sooner, use its [hooks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dhcpcd#Hooks) feature.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer @grawity, I have updated the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

good new, I found the problem.

Actually, I needed two COMMIT, one for the first rules and another one for nat rules.

Fixed.

Comment: It's actually one `COMMIT` per table...(I assume you have a rule in `*filter`)

Comment: What's a table?

Comment: http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html （See about `-t`)

Comment: ty. My attempt to set up the Pi router as I  planned failed. I create another question to focus on the routing issues.